# What new technology did Voyager bring home?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Throughout the series, Voyager gains significant upgrades that put it ahead of many of its contemporary Starfleet vessels. However, several of these upgrades would not have been truly new to Starfleet. So, excluding any technology that we know another Starfleet ship to have had at or before the time of Voyager's return home, what new technology did Voyager bring home with it? Furthermore, which of these technologies weren't obtained from the future?

Comment: Transwarp technology for one.

Comment: the mobile-emitter? It came from the mid-1990s...from a certain point of view

Comment: Warp travel slingshot arrays.

Comment: @Paulie_D Transwarp was a thing in the original Star Trek with William Shatner, because in one of the movies Scotty disables a transwarp vessel that would otherwise have been sent to bring the *Enterprise* home after Admiral Kirk commandeers her.

Comment: What about the time travel technology "future" Janeway acquired so she could go back in time to shorten the trip home? Didn't the Voyager crew get a chance to check out the gizmo on her shuttle? Or was it captured/destroyed by the Borg?

Comment: A set of *"I went to the Delta Quadrant and all I got was this lousy t-shirt"* t-shirts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Based on Voyager's [Memory Alpha entry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Voyager)**

(not exhaustive, read the whole wiki)

- holo-emitters (So the doctor could walk around the ship and participate in more episodes)
- a tachyon core
- transwarp coil
- Detailed information on the Borg from both 7 of 9 and Delta Quadrant inhabitants
- More accurate charts of the Delta Quadrant
- quantum slipstream drive
- Graviton catapult (at least some ideas around it)
- Nano-viruses and access to the Borg's Transwarp hub thanks to Future Janeway

If you're looking for an episode that said something likes "Would have sucked to be on that ship, but we got all these cool new super-technologies like slipstream drive and holo-emitters!" There isn't one.  The closes you'll get is the series finale with future Janeway.

Comment: Episodes aside, one wonders if your lasts paragraph has an answer in the expanded material.

Comment: They also got first-hand experience with the `Spacial Trajector` which could teleport people up to 40,000 light years, but which used anti-neutrino as a base which was incompatible with Federation technology.

Answer (score -1):

The only ones I'm sure about based on their use in the final episode are:

- The mobile holo-emitter.

and

- The armour and nano-virus technologies future Janeway stole and used to kill the Borg.

These technologies are actually Starfleet technology from later time frames that were brought back through time by Janeway/*Voyager* at various times. There are no other technologies we see in use by any Starfleet vessel or personnel within the series as far as I know.